# How to give instructions to a script

Tags: php, templates, design-patterns, webpage-rendering

**Description:**
The title is not as describable, but couldn't think of a better one. I have made myself a view processor that compiles the view (I am using tailored MVC) and the problem that I have is that when it 'compiles' the view ie (capture the output before rendering it (trimming + compression at high level)). Anyway this works as expected with no issues, but when the view compiler hits a dynamic page it ain't dynamic anymore ie. if I use the same template for two pages or the content is based on the user viewing the site, he will see the compiled version of the prev user instead of the one that he is supposed to be seeing. Here is my method at the moment:

1. determining the view which is to be rendered based on the routes
2. Starting gz_compression
3. including the template
4. Capturing the output in a variable for rendering when necessary
5. Clean the gzip buffer

**Question:**
What I exactly want is a method to add 'instructions' to the compiler, whether or not the file should be compiled and saved or rendered directly.

**PS:**

I couldn't think of any pattern that will do the trick as long as it does not require the creation of separate models and such, any option is acceptable and a simple implementation would be very good. Sorry for my bad english it is not my native.

Cheers!

Comment: what is your question ?

Comment: I know i didn't asked the question correctly, but my head is a mess. Sorry! See '**Question**'

Comment: why donot you pickup the filename which is similar to controller action like in cakephp?

Comment: the issue stays the same, you see when the compiler captures the output if the request uri is 'module/controller/action' it will stay the same, now i am storing the files with the md5_file() value as filename, but i do not cache the template code, but the execution result, so the file stays the same(so does the hash of it) if i do not change the template itself. and if user1 hits the page first all other users will see the page of user1, not their own. MY problem is how to 'tell' the compiler not to compile a view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added a 'switch' variable that defaults to `TRUE` (compile by default), and a static method to turn it off when necessary. This is a good walkthrough for the moment, anyway nay better suggestions are welcome.